# How do I regenerate connection string for Azure?

Tags: java, azure

I use access keys to authenticate my application when making requests to my Azure storage account. I'd like to regenerate them using API. `CloudStorageAccount` class allows to get credentials but there is no method (or I can't find it at least) to regenerate access keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [Azure Storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts) endpoint for regenerating storage keys that you could use.

The endpoint looks like

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/regenerateKey?api-version=2017-06-01
```

and expects as body which key you want to regenerate, e.g. key1 or key2:

```
{
  "keyName": "key2"
}
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/regeneratekey) page for more info.